# How to stop collapsing other sections when one of them is expanded in bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have an accordion like this:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
       
       <!-- First -->
        <div class="card">
            
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link text-primary px-0 text-uppercase" type="button"
                            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
                            aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        First block                        </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse " aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                 data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">

                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input filter" id="automatic" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic">One</label>
                    </div>                          
                       
                        
                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input filter" id="automatic" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic">Two</label>
                    </div>                          
                       
                        
                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input filter" id="automatic" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic">Three</label>
                    </div>                          
                       
                        
                                            
                       
                                                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
      <!-- Second block -->
      <div class="card">
            
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link text-primary px-0 text-uppercase" type="button"
                            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true"
                            aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        Second Block                        </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse " aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
                 data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">

                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input" id="automatic2" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic2">One</label>
                    </div>                          
                       
                        
                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input" id="automatic2" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic2">Two</label>
                    </div>                          
                       
                        
                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input" id="automatic2" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic2">Three</label>
                    </div>                          
                       
                        
                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input" id="automatic2" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic2">Four</label>
                    </div>                          
                     
                                                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       
      <!-- Third block -->  
      <div class="card">
            
            <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link text-primary px-0 text-uppercase" type="button"
                            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true"
                            aria-controls="collapseThree">
                        Third block                        </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse " aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                 data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">

                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input" id="automatic3" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic3">One</label>
                    </div>                          
                       
                        
                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input" id="automatic3" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic3">Two</label>
                    </div>                          
                       
                        
                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input" id="automatic3" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic3">Three</label>
                    </div>                          
                       
                        
                     <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="automatic3" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="automatic3">Four</label>
                    </div>                          
                       
                                            
                                                
                       
                                                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I use bootstrap 4 to make it collapsable/expandable. Now the behavior is this: when i click on one block, it expands, then when i click on another block, this another block expands, but previuos block collapses. I want to make another behavior - not to collapse previuosly expanded blocks when clicking on another blocks. If something is opened - let it keeps opened. How can i do it with bootstrap? Here is jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dLa4p0uc/

Answer (score 0):

So finally i just deleted :

> data-parent="#accordionExample"

everywhere in this example, and it is what i need. Yeaah